# Show button in a list view on swiping one item from that list

Tags: android, swipe

I am working on an android application and I want to show a button when user swipe a particular item of list.

Here is my xaml in which I have a button and few other items. I am using this xml in my list view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="#f1eff0">


    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible" android:id="@+id/tb1">

        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/createdBy" android:typeface="normal" 
                android:singleLine="true" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/postText" android:typeface="normal"
                android:singleLine="true" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/btnDelete" android:textColor="#ffffff" android:visible="Gone"
                android:background="@color/hover_button" android:text="Delete"
                android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal" android:typeface="normal"
                android:layout_marginLeft="320dp" />
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/postDate" android:typeface="normal"
                android:singleLine="true" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="normal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have already searched on google but could not understand the examples I am new for android please help me.

Comment: Yes [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/937313/android-basic-gesture-detection) this link

Comment: sooooo ? what is the precise issue ?

Comment: It does not work for me in my list. I mean I am unable to understand where should I put that code in my list adapter or in my class where I am adding list and in both case where to put it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following link will help you in implementing the swipe delete action in the listview.

[Swipe delete operation in listview](http://andhradroid.wordpress.com/2012/07/05/how-to-implement-swipe-delete-operation-in-android-like-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to implement 47Degree Swipe List View (Works ultimate)

Get more information on implementing Swipe List View here,

[Slide ListView Item on Android like iPhone Mail app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391919/slide-listview-item-on-android-like-iphone-mail-app/20036754#20036754)

[Need help to implement 47degree Android-SwipeListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848610/need-help-to-implement-47degree-android-swipelistview)

Accept & up-vote answers if you find them useful.