# How to integrate 47degree android-swipelistview for swiping android ListViewItem to project

Tags: android, listview, swipe, swipeview

Actually I want to implement a list view with swiping elements.

I found this library: http://www.androidviews.net/2013/03/swipelistview/.

When i import this library to eclipse my package structure is like below :

[image]

In swipelistview project I added the support and nineoldandroid jar files.

My problem is swipelistview is not library project and how can add project to SwipeListViewExampleActivity

I have tried number of ways to solve the problem: by checking the build path,deleting bin folder and importing the jar files, but not got any help in solving the problem.

Also I could also find any tutorial to use this library in eclipse.Has anyone used this library or faced problem same as me,then please guide me how to integrate this library to project.

Or is there any other library to perform to implement this kind of functionality.

Comment: first check and re check you must not have multiple Android-sport-library more than one time 

If you have refrence libraries than make it sure you have same type of android support Library and then if you have multiple instance remove the other instances clean project and run it

Comment: @UsmanKurd I have check there are no multiple support library added. Did you have implement the above library

Comment: then you might have copied the jar from the library and evem imported the library in your build path. check it. it freqquently happens with me

Comment: i meant to say that the jar file must be present in both **libs** and **android referenced libraries** folder

Comment: @MaulikSheth no i have only jar file in libs folder.

Comment: @NidhiGondhia you can try doing this, go in your projects properties, remove all the jars that you have imported, add the entire library **47 degree swipe** _as a_ **library** from the **Android** tab.. this will make sure there is only one .jar file of the library 47degree

Comment: if you have already done the above, then the problem is that you are adding the **47degree** library in you build path _and also_ you are copying the jar in your _libs_ folder and then including in your _build path_ which results in two jar's. one from _libs_ and other from library itself

Comment: @MaulikSheth please see my ques edit.

Comment: android support v4 jar you are including it in the 47degree project but it also is included by default in your own project. check your projects folder called _**android private libraries**_ if it includes the v4 jar then you found the problem. _v4 jar_ exists both in your prject and in 47degree project @NidhiGondhia

Comment: or check the project _swipelistview_ you copied v4jar in it. check its _android private libraries_ package if it already includes the v4jar

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same problems.
To import the library, please check my answer in this link: [Here, I explain how import the library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27048429/2554730)

In my case, to implement the SwipeListView, I placed the classes and resources of exemple project into my project, then I have customized the layout, dimens and styles, worked for me.