# List with sliding action

Tags: android, listview, slidingmenu

I'm trying to make a dynamic list that also has an action when the entry tile is slid to the left. I'm basically trying to make a list like the contact list on the Samsung galaxy devices. This contact list has the following features adjusting according to the number of entries, if you slide the entry to the left you can send the message, and if you send it to the right you can call the contact.

Here is a picture of the contact app.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oslSi.png

Here is the sliding action when I slid the tile to the left.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfkcN.png

I'm wondering what I should use for the list. A listview? What should I do to get the sliding effect?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slide ListView Item on Android like iPhone Mail app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19391919/slide-listview-item-on-android-like-iphone-mail-app)