# Android using custom view PullToRefreshSwipeListView

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh, swipeview

I am trying to use both  [PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh) and [SwipeListView](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview#download) libraries in listview using [PullToRefreshSwipeListView](https://code.google.com/p/fitup/source/browse/android/trunk/libprojects/PullToRefresh/src/com/handmark/pulltorefresh/library/PullToRefreshSwipeListView.java?r=279) custom view class. I have implemented it like that:

First I have imported PullToRefresh library into my project then I have added a  [SwipeListView Jar File](https://oss.sonatype.org/content/groups/public/com/fortysevendeg/android/swipelistview/1.0-SNAPSHOT/) into PullToRefresh library projet by making a libs folder in it. Then I have added PullToRefreshSwipeListView class in the src folder(com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library) of PullToRefresh library project. Finally I am trying to implement this custom class PullToRefreshSwipeListView  into my project's xml as:

```
<com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView
    xmlns:swipe="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ptr="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/lv_Inbox"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="#19000000"
    android:dividerHeight="2dp"
    android:fadingEdge="none"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true"
    ptr:ptrAnimationStyle="flip" >

    <libs.swipelistview.SwipeListView
        android:id="@+id/users_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:cacheColorHint="#0000"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0px"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        swipe:swipeActionLeft="reveal" />
</com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView>
```

But I am getting error in xml as:

- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeActionLeft' in package
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeActionLeft' in package
- error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'swipeMode' in package

It does not get any of the swipe attribute but If I remove swipe attributes. It is working fine for only PullToRefresh. I am following [this](http://kyogs.blogspot.com/2014/05/android-list-view-with-pull-to-refresh.html) link to implement it. Any Solution/Comments will be most appreciated.

Comment: there is no need to use external libraries. You use swipe refresh layout and android swipe list item natively. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html and swipe example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857775/android-listview-row-delete-animation

Comment: No, you can not compare SwipeRefreshLayout with PullToRefresh. Android support library class SwipeRefreshLayout does not provide way to add action bar hint "Pull to refresh".

Comment: Have you get an perfect ans for this? I have also same problem. I am not get any proper solution...How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to merge PullToRefresh into SwipeListView library ? I have used PullToRefresh with SwipeListView without no problems (just imported using gradle not JARs).

You are getting these errors because you have not copied **swipelistview__attrs.xml** from *res/values* in SwipeListView library ([this file](https://github.com/47deg/android-swipelistview/blob/master/swipelistview/src/main/res/values/swipelistview__attrs.xml))

Comment: I am working on Eclipse not Android studio cant use gradle. Thats why I am using jar file of swipelistview

Comment: Have you tried copying swipelistview__attrs.xml file into project/pulltorefresh?

Comment: How are you using PullToRefresh with SwipeListView? Can you post some code here. I think there is need to add custom ListView item in xml file for both PullToRefresh and SwipeListView libraries. PullToRefresh adds it like <com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView and swipelistview adds its own custom listview item in xml like this <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView So what kind of ListView tag are you using in you XML file?

Comment: Ok I did change my code according to link you have provided. I have edited the code in my question description. I have separated two libraries now and added in to my project separately. Now I am not getting any error in XML. But how to use both of them in Java code? As both PullToRefresh and SwipeRefresh returns the listview object in code. How to use them. Should I make objects of both seperatly but then i would have two listviews? Please tell me how you did in you code? Thanks

Comment: PullToRefreshLayout is not ListView. You must make your Activity or Fragment implements OnRefreshListener. In onCreateView or OnCreate add these lines: mPullToRefreshLayout = (PullToRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.pull_refresh); ActionBarPullToRefresh.from(getActivity()).allChildrenArePullable().listener(this).setup(mPullToRefreshLayout);

Comment: I am getting crash in while importing library into my project. So following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848610/need-help-to-implement-47degree-android-swipelistview I copied all Java classes into my project by creating a package. And then tried to access it into xml but still getting crash. java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.whizpool.xyc/com.xyc.DashBoardActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class libs.swipelistview.SwipeListView

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60007/discussion-between-nouman-bhatti-and-yuraj).

Answer (score 1):

```
better you go with 
swiperefresh layout

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html
```

Comment: I want flip effect when user pulltorefresh like Facebook Android app. SwipeRefreshLayout provides Gmail like effect when pulltorefresh. Also SwipeRefreshLayout is only for vertical swipe gesture. I am trying to implement here horizontal swipe on list item. So even if I implement SwipeRefreshLayout I have to implement SwipeListView library. And the problem remains there